# Put elements in stream and return an object

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

In akka, I want to put the elements in  stream and return an object. I know the elements could be a source to run a graph. But how can I put the element and return an object on runtime?

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.QueueOfferResult.{Dropped, Enqueued, Failure, QueueClosed}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.Array.range
import scala.util.Success

object StreamElement {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("StreamElement")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val (queue, value) = Source
    .queue[Int](10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .map(x => {
      x * x
    })
    .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(false))(Keep.both)
    .run()

    range(0, 10)
      .map(x => {
        queue.offer(x).onComplete {
          case Success(Enqueued) => {
          }

          case Success(Dropped) => {}
          case _ => {
             println("others")
          }
        }
      })
    }
}
```

How can I get the value returned?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to feed a Stream element-wise with a Scala collection rather than a Source.  In particular, since you've already composed a Stream with materialized values to be captured in a Source Queue and a publisher Sink, I think a good use case would be to wrap the Scala collection in a Source and create a subscriber Source to collect the wanted values.

Comment: Thanks. you mean  ".runWith(Sink.actorRefWithAck)" ?

Comment: Actually, I am very new for Akka-stream. For my case, would you please also give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to show sample code as comments.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you want to return the int value for each element.
So you could create the flow, then connect to source and Sink for each time.

```
package tech.parasol.scala.akka

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.QueueOfferResult.{Dropped, Enqueued, Failure, QueueClosed}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.Array.range
import scala.util.Success

object StreamElement {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("StreamElement")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val flow = Flow[Int]
    .buffer(16, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .map(x => x * x)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    range(0, 10)
      .map(x => {
        Source.single(x).via(flow).runWith(Sink.head)
      }.map( v => println("v ===> " + v)
      ))
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there  some performance issue for create the source and sink?

Comment: I tested it before, the performance is ok. You also could test it as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me why the Scala collection isn't fed to the Stream as a Source in your sample code.  Given that you've already composed a Stream with materialized values to be captured in a Source Queue and a publisher Sink, you could create a subscriber Source using [`Source.fromPublisher`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/Source/fromPublisher.html) to collect the wanted values, as shown below:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()  // Not needed for Akka 2.6+

val (queue, pub) = Source
  .queue[Int](10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .map(x =>  x * x)
  .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(false))(Keep.both)
  .run()

val fromQueue = Source(0 until 10).runForeach(queue.offer(_))

val source = Source.fromPublisher(pub)

source.runForeach(x => print(x + " "))
// Output:
// 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

Comment: If it is a request -> a response mode, for example, a http request .via(flow)  then a http response. By your example, how could do this?

Comment: @YouXiang-Wang, the proposed approach was only to make use of the SourceQueue/publisher that OP already had (although I might've misunderstood what OP wanted).  I wouldn't take such approach in your use case.

Comment: Basically, for http request -> response scenario,  we have to use akka ask pattern. So do we have another method without ask pattern to handle such http request -> response scenario?  I am also looking for this method.  :-)

Comment: It's unclear to me what your specific business logic requirement is.  Perhaps consider posting a question along with sample request/response/flow requirement.